# Why my forEach loop does not create the DOM elements from the array.length?

Tags: javascript, arrays, dom, foreach

I have been dealing with an issue for a while now.
My problem is that I iterate an array with a loop but in the end, it just creates a single element. But my goal is to create a grid with cards

Here is my code.

```
    var array_of_elements = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9, 10, 10, 11, 11, 12, 12];
    var shuffled_array = shuffle(array_of_elements);
    var deck_of_cards = document.createElement("div");
    var cards = "";

  function newGame() {
            deck_of_cards.setAttribute("id", "card_deck");
            document.body.appendChild(deck_of_cards);

            /*  Loop throught all the array elemets and apply the class box*/
            shuffled_array.forEach(createElementBoard);
            deck_of_cards.innerHTML = cards;
        }

        /* Boarder creation  */
        function createElementBoard(i_cards) {
            cards = "<div class='box box-" + i_cards + "'></div>";
            return cards;
        }
newGame();
```

The code does not produce any errors.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: `shuffled_array.forEach(createElementBoard)` is not calling any function.. instead should be `shuffled_array.forEach(createElementBoard())`

Comment: Where are deck_of_cards and shuffled_array initially defined? For example, the code, as written, is using setAttribute on undefined (deck_of _cards hasn't been defined)

Comment: what is `shuffled_array`?

Comment: [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) doesn't return anything, therefore you have to perform the action within the `forEach()` call, rather than returning content to the calling context.

Comment: I'd suggest using a javascript debugger (e.g. Chrome Developer Tools) and actually tracing thru and seeing what's going on.

Comment: For some reason, @Luca deleted my variable declarations. Can you please tell me why my friend? Is this some kind of Githubs policy not to include the variables?

Comment: ...I don't know how that happened

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of problems here.

What you're doing, is assigning the HTML for *one* card to the global variable `cards`, and overwriting it each time through your loop, so at the end, it's the HTML for just the last card.

If you change the line:

```
cards = "<div class='box box-" + i_cards + "'></div>";
```

to:

```
cards += "<div class='box box-" + i_cards + "'></div>";
```

It'll make the code *work*, but that's not the best solution.

Functions can return a value, communicating instead via a global is bad practice. Consider if you needed to re-run this function, whose responsibility would it be to reset `cards`? What if you ran it from multiple places, how would you ensure that they didn't interfere with each other?

Instead, consider this:

```
shuffled_array.forEach(function(i) {
    deck_of_cards.innerHTML += createElementBoard(i)
});
```

And stop `cards` being global:

```
function createElementBoard(i_cards) {
    var card = "<div class='box box-" + i_cards + "'></div>";
    return card;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @SpoonMeiser. It worked! I would like to ask something though! If I had the var card set to let card and declare it in the global scope would that be an issue?

Comment: It's not a good idea to communicate with a function via a global variable. What happens if your function is called from two places?

Answer (score 1):

[Array.prototype.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) iterates over an Array but does not return anything (you shouldn't even be getting that "single element" (edit: as SpoonMeiser commented below, that seems to be an artifact of your global variable use)).

If you want to set innerHTML, you need a function that creates a string. This could be done in two ways:

You can use [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to create an array of strings, and then use [Array.prototype.join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to convert them to a single one.

```
function newGame() {
    deck_of_cards.setAttribute("id", "card_deck");
    document.body.appendChild(deck_of_cards);

    /*  Loop throught all the array elemets and apply the class box*/
    const cards = shuffled_array.map(createElementBoard);
    deck_of_cards.innerHTML = cards.join("");
}

/* Boarder creation  */
function createElementBoard(i_cards) {
    const card = "<div class='box box-" + i_cards + "'></div>";
    return card;
}
newGame();
```

Or, you can use [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

Answer (score 0):

This is not possibly either you save cards data in `global` variable or put `forEach` implementation locally.

```
function newGame() {
    deck_of_cards.setAttribute("id", "card_deck");
    document.body.appendChild(deck_of_cards);

    /*  Loop throught all the array elemets and apply the class box*/
    var cards = "";
    shuffled_array.forEach(function(i_cards) {
        cards += "<div class='box box-" + i_cards + "'></div>";

    });
    deck_of_cards.innerHTML = cards;
}
newGame();
```